# Spark SQL: Update if exists, else ignore

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, kudu, apache-kudu

Is there a way to fastly execute a "Update if exists, ignore otherwise" dealing with Spark SQL and storing into Kudu?

Context is: IoT platform, lots of data received and platform resources limited.
I'm inserting/updating data into a Kudu Storage using Spark Streaming.

Connected devices send 2 kinds of message :

- The first message: a complete message (id device, id session, device data, session data)
- All the other messages are parcial: )id device, id session, session data)

Due to resources limitations, my intention is using a single-table model:

- When I receive the first message, I insert it
- When other messages are received, registry is updated.

But life is not perfect, and sometimes the "first" message is lost and not persisted. In this case, I want to "ignore" the device, that's why I can't use upsert.

I discarded the possibility to store parcial messages and next delete all the messages with null device data, as the scan and delete are consumming my limited resources.

And the only way I found is to perform a join to look for existing PK and update their corresponding registry, which is consumming lots of resources, too.

So the question is, as an Update if exists, else Insert is available, how could a Update if exists, else ignore it could be implemented to "updateIfExists" a spark DF in an optimized way?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Cheloute,

The solution that I Can think is not to write WHEN "NOT MATched " condition.
  Can you try this something like this:

    MERGE INTO events
    USING updates
    ON events.eventId = updates.eventId
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET events.data = updates.data

Source:

    https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html#language-sql

Comment: @Aditya.Kommu Thanks for your advice, but what you're suggesting only apply on DeltaLake storage layer, not Kudu layer... I'm not creating a new development but modifying an existing one, change the storage layer is not an option for now :(